# Why shift a bit using sll and such in MIPs Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, sll

So I understand somewhat what the command sll is doing, as I read [this](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-12/ass12_2.html) and its pretty much just shifting all the bits left by 1. I'm just wondering why would I do this?

I have an assignment from class with an example of it...
Where $s6 and $s7 is the base address for an array and $s1/$s2 are just some variables.

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2
add $t0, $s6, $t0
sll $t1, $s1, 2
add $t1, $s7, $t1
...
```

Why shift a bit? What is it doing in simple terms? My first thought it has something to do with indexing the variables in the array...but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> its pretty much just shifting all the bits left by 1

The example they showed was a shift by 1 bit. The `sll` instruction isn't limited to just shifting by 1 bit; you can specify a shift amount in the range 0..31 (a shift by 0 might seem useless, but `SLL $zero, $zero, 0` is used to encode a `NOP` on MIPS).

[A logical left shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) by `N` bits can be used as a fast means of multiplying by `2^N` (2 to the power of N). So the instruction `sll $t0, $s0, 2` is multiplying `$s0` by 4 (2^2) and writing back to `$t0`. This is useful e.g. when scaling offsets to be used when accessing a word array.

Answer (score 2):

Shifting a number one bit to the left is the same as multiplying that number by 2.
More generally, shifting a number N bits to the left is the same as multiplying that number by 2^N.

It is widely used to compute the offset of an array, when each element of the array has a size that is a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the program there is simple sll applied on $s0 and $s2 registers!
In instruction sll $t0, $s0, 2, the value of register $s0 will be multiplied by 4.
You can clear more at [Shift left logical example](http://www.assemblylanguagetuts.com/shift-left-logical-mips-sll/)